# d.rast problem in GRASS command line

Tags: grass-gis, windows-8, command-line, grass.script

In response to @gene I type `d.mon` in command line, getting a popout GUI look like this:

[image]

I choose the top three flags(-l, -L, -p), and I got this:

[image]

And I don't know what to type in 4 blanks below:

[image]

Then I close GUI window, typing command `d.mon start=x0`, and got this:

[image]

---

As I type command `d.rast hc`(I have a raster file named **hc** and I want to display it), I got this：

[image]

and except this I got nothing and the map is not displayed.

How can I do to make the display succeed？

I am using GRASS 6.4.3 under windows 8.1 64-bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [d.rast](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/d.rast.html)

> d.rast displays raster map layer(s) name in the active display frame on the graphics monitor.

You need to first start and select a graphics monitor with [d.mon](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/d.mon.html)  but from [d.mon doesn't work (WinGrass commandline)](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/339)

> X monitors do not exist in native MS windows. You must use the GUI

On Mac OS X or Linux with a X monitor:

```
GRASS 6.4.3 (geol):~ > d.rast ortho.shaded@mymapset
WARNING: No socket to connect to for monitor <x0>.
ERROR: No graphics device selected
```

start x0 monitor:

```
GRASS 6.4.3 (geol):~ > d.mon start=x0
using default visual which is TrueColor
ncolors: 16777216
Graphics driver [x0] started
GRASS 6.4.3 (geol):~ > d.rast ortho.shaded@mymapset
100%
```

If you still want to check your available monitors use:

```
d.mon -p -l -L
```